# Sort feature with dust.js

Tags: javascript, dust.js

XSLT lets you sort nodes when rendering them with a template. Does Linked In's version of dust.js have this?

If so, if I had this JSON view:

```
{
    people: [ 
        { name: "Fred", sort_order: 3 },
        { name: "Harry", sort_order: 2 },
        { name: "Linda", sort_order: 4 },
        { name: "Mary", sort_order: 6 },
        { name: "Bob", sort_order: 5 },
        { name: "Joey", sort_order: 1 }
    ]
}
```

and I wanted this output:

Joey

Harry

Fred

Linda

Bob

Mary

how would the template differ from this simple one?

```
{#people}
    <br/>{name}
{/people}
```

This would be executed in a browser.

Comment: I'm not sure about dust, but javascript arrays have a built in `.sort` method that lets you choose how you'd like to sort your array. You can use that to sort the arrays and then pass them sorted to dust.js if that's an acceptable solution to you.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but I don't want to affect the data when rendering it with a dust.js template.

Answer (score 4):

To do this in Dust, you would need to write a helper to do the sorting.  There would probably be a healthy debate on if this data manipulation should be done in the dust template, or done in the layer above it that is passing the data in.

You can find details about writing a dust helper here:

- https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-Writing_a_dust_helper

Here is an example of what a sort helper might look like:

```
dust.helpers.customSort = function (chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    params.items.sort(function(a, b) {
        return ((a.sort_order < b.sort_order) ? -1 : ((a.sort_order > b.sort_order) ? 1 : 0));
    });

    return chunk;
};
```

Here is a jsfiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jamsyoung/k3SNN/

Answer (score 0):

Just add Dust Context Helper!

```
"helperName": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
     var val = context.get("nameOfProperty");
     nameOfProperty.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.nameOfProperty[param] - b.nameOfProperty[param];
     });
   return racers;
}
```

Details here  [Dust.js](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/context-helpers/) Race Winners example